# Get function from server side using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a javascript function on the server side that will get data from data from JSON file and it works. However, i don't know how to create a java script function on my client side to get the function below and get data from that function. It would been a great help if you guys can show me what i need to do. Thanks in advance

```js
function getData()
 var fs = require('fs');
 var ICCID = require('./masterlist.json')
if (ICCID.length != 0) {
 var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*ICCID.length);
 var pickedID = ICCID[index];
    ICCID.splice(index, 1);  // This removes the picked element from the array
    fs.writeFile("masterlist.json", JSON.stringify(ICCID), function(err){
     if (err){
      return consolo.log(err);
     }
    });
 }
  else{
    console.log("Sorry, There is no more ID");
  }
  return pickedID;
}
```

Comment: Are you using node.js?

Comment: yes, i am using node.js since i am doing it as a local host

Comment: Have you heard of socket.io? It's what I use to talk between server and client with node.js. There are many options available though.

Comment: I was creating an array with bunch of random ID. Then i have a function that fetch random ID without duplicate. However, every time it fetch an ID, it picked ID from the original list again and then duplicate happen. So that's why i choose json. I don't know how to remove ID from an array so at the end if i have no ID left, it give me an alert like the above function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) to integrate your back-end and front-end javascript`s.

- [A frontend JavaScript framework to pair with Node.js](https://blog.andyet.com/2015/04/14/frontend-frameworks-to-pair-with-node/).